# If we regard a field $F$ as a vector space then it can only have two subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I would like to show that given a field $F$ and a vector space $V=F$ (so we are viewing this field as a vector space), then $V$ has only two subspaces. I know that these two subspaces are $\{0\}$ and $V$ and I know how to show that each one of them is a subspace. However, my issue is to show that these two are the only subspaces. I have tried to assume that there is a third subspace other than these two and somehow arrive at a contradiction, but so far no luck. Would someone please be able to help?

Comment: What can you say about the dimension of any subspace of $F$?

Comment: Well, if it is $\{0\}$ you are done. Suppose it isn't $\{0\}$. Then what do you know?

Comment: The field $\Bbb R$ of real numbers is an infinite dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb Q$ of rational numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $\{0\}$ is a subspace. Now assume that $W \neq \{0\}$ is a subspace of $V$. We show that $W = V$. since $W \neq \{0\}$, $\exists c \in W, \text{ such that } c \neq 0$. but then from axioms of vector space it follows that $\dfrac{1}{c} \cdot c = 1 \in W$ (as $\dfrac{1}{c} \in F$). But $W$ itself is a vector space over field $F$. Thus, again from axioms  of vector spaces, it follows that $k \cdot 1 \in W, \forall k \in F$. but $k \cdot 1 = k$. Hence the result follows. 

(This proof does not invoke any result related to dimension. Also, I have used same symbols  for vectors in $V (=F)$ and scalars in $F$. Hope it does not lead to any confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $F$ is being viewed as a vector space over itself, note that it has dimension $1$. Why? Take the multiplicative identity $e \in F$. Note that $\{e\}$ forms a basis for $F$. Then, any subspace of $F$ either has dimension $1$ or $0$. If it's $0$, the only subspace it can be is $\{0\}$. If it's $1$, then it's all of $F$.

**Edit:** An Alternative Approach

Let $V'$ be a subspace of $F$. Suppose $V'$ is not $\{0\}$. Therefore, there exists non-zero $v \in V' \subset F$. If $m \in F$, then note that $m = (mv^{-1})v$ where $v^{-1}$ exists because $v \neq 0$, and $V'$ is a subspace (so we have a notion of scalar multiplication in that subspace). Hence, $m$ can be viewed as a scalar multiple of $v \implies F \subset V'$ (remember your subspace axioms! $v \in V'$ implies $cv \in V'$ for all $c \in F$). It follows $F = V'$

Comment: What if I don't have access to the concept of a dimension. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: Just edited my answer

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help.